# Should there be a [catalog] tag (e.g. shortest in every language)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm wondering if there should be a tag for questions that compile a list of best score by language.

A recent example is [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/34718). Questions similar to this have a snippet the keeps a list of the shortest solution by programming language.

I think it'd be useful to have such a tag, in order to find challenges to add your new language's solution to, for example.

Answer (score 6):

No there shouldn't be a tag. They aren't really different from a normal challenge, except that they focus on simple/standard programming exercises and explicitly ask for answers in non-competitive languages. That makes the tag seem very much like a rather arbitrary meta tag.

I would be in favour of collecting them somewhere though (e.g. in a meta post). **Edit:** [This has been done.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7225/8478) (And will be amended with an overview snippet some time soon.) For more arguing why we shouldn't treat catalogues any different from normal challenges, [see this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7494/8478).

Comment: I like seeing answers in languages other than CJam and Pyth, so I think we should have more questions like that.

Comment: @mbomb007 I completely agree. We have already collected a list of potential future challenges of this kind in chat, but consensus was not to post them more often than every other week, because they take a lot of effort from the community to fill with diverse and interesting answers.

Comment: I'd like to see a tag for this, mainly so that people know that there are no accepted answers and the point is to get as many different solutions/algorithms as possible.

Comment: @VoteToClose My point is that such a tag would tell people that *only* challenges with that tag are aiming "to get as many different solutions/algorithms as possible" which I think is very counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be a tag. Tags are used to find questions similar to each other without having to rely on the (sometimes rather naïve) "Related" engine used by StackExchange. The obvious exceptions are the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), [popularity-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-challenge) and [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), which are there to distinguish question **types** (much like the language tags on StackOverflow)

The new [catalogue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catalogue) tag should **not** intend to replace these tags - as Martin Büttner pointed out, they are not fundamentally different from either of these tags. But then, is [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) fundamentally different from [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory); is [regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression) fundamentally different from [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)? My point is that tags are in general not used to identify fundamentally different questions, but to find related questions.

This new tag should also be considered as a device to find **related questions**. The fact that there is [a Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7225/8478) doing exactly that, shows that there is a demand for this. Why would we want a meta post, which should be linked from all included questions to easily find related questions, when there is a fully developed [tags](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) system that does exactly that?

Comment: I think the point I'm trying to make is these challenges are not any more related than any other challenges, except for the fact that they cover simple "standard programming tasks", but that's an entirely subjective categorisation. The purpose of the snippet I want to write for the meta post is more like a to-do list of which of these challenges are still missing certain languages.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Sorry, I misread that bit (and edited accordingly). Still, I disagree that it's an "entirely subjective categorization", since they are usually clearly described to be a catalog, and they are even a special [exception from being off-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7489/32352).

Comment: That isn't exactly a consensus, seeing that my competing answer has the same net votes.

Comment: Tags are intended to be used to find questions that are similar or related by *topic*. [arithmetic] is a topic, [string] is a topic. [catalog] isn't a topic. Our challenge-type tags are already an exception to this, but I don't see a great reason to make another one.