# Catalogue of Catalogues

Tags: discussion

I am currently developing a new language and thought that catalogue questions such as [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/69279) and [Golf you a Quine for great good](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/69279) are good challenges that a language should be able to do.

However, it can be kinda difficult to find all the catalogues as they aren't all linked and not always the most upvoted.

Therefore, I would like this question to be a "catalogue" of the catalogue questions. Below is a list of all catalogue questions. If you can't find a catalogue that you **know** meets the criteria, feel free to add it below.

For clarity, a catalogue challenge is one with a Stack Snippet (or Catalogue) at the bottom and/or has the rule

> Unlike our usual rules, feel free to use a language (or language version) even if it's newer than this challenge. If anyone wants to abuse this by creating a language where the empty program generates , then congrats for paving the way for a very boring answer.

## Catalogues

- [Add two numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84260/69279)
- [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/69279)
- [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/69279)
- [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58615/69279)
- ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/69279)
- [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/66833)
- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62732/66833)
- [Simple cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62230/66833)
- [Shortest infinite loop producing no output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59347/66833)

Comment: IMO, this post would be more useful with the list in the main post itself, rather than having a bunch of answers.

Comment: I have [this gist](https://gist.github.com/m-ender/61e602f78a247be64ee327a7d119844f) for a similar purpose. They aren't all "catalogues", and it's certainly not complete, but they are all challenges I like to test new esolangs on if possible.

Comment: Also, I don't think we'll feature this, because we only have so many slots on the sidebar, but we're considering to replace the sandbox with a single meta post that acts as a hub for all relevant meta links for newer users (similar to [meta-tag:faq] but more discoverable). In that case, this could potentially be included, depending on how useful it ends up being.

Comment: My understanding was that catalogues had been [abandoned as an idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7686/194) and that posting new ones was strongly discouraged. This question per se seems to encourage them and hence be a step in the wrong direction; making it part of an FAQ would amplify the problem.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think the general idea is a good one (evidently, I've collected such a list myself because I found it useful). It would probably better not to focus on the catalogue nature though. Just as a list of simple/standard challenges so people can take new languages for a spin.

Comment: @MartinEnder, if the focus of the question is on "What should I use to test the power of my new language?" rather than "Should this be in the PPCG FAQ?" then surely it's not on topic for codegolf.meta?

Comment: [Search for catalogs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=Catalog+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano), [Search for catalogues](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=Catalogue+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano).