# What are our specific abbreviations and terms?

Tags: discussion, support, faq, new-users, chat

Newcomers to codegolf.SE are often compelled to ask what many of our abbreviations and terms mean. Let us list them here so this information always will be easily available.

[Return to FAQ index](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280)

Comment: While I like this post, it isn't a complete solution to the problem as newcomers won't necessarily be able to find it. When dealing with newcomers acronyms should be avoided unless obvious from context as in `Welcome to PPCG`.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37584339#37584339

Comment: @LevelRiverSt what the heck is a PPCG?

Comment: @Adám I wasn't criticising in any way. I think this post is a great idea. But the fact remains that there is a lot for newcomers to learn when they start here and some people aren't very helpful. according to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11807/15599 someone actually commented `Y U NO CRITERIA?` The fact that we mention winning criteria in our site rules does not make it acceptable to leave a cryptic insult to a newcomer who doesn't know them. Nor should your post make people think it acceptable to comment `Y U NO ABBREVIATIONS` or similar.

Comment: @carusocomputing you just proved my point! ;-) I think if a new user were to be told `WELCOME TO PPCG` they would be able to work out that `PPCG` was some kind of name for the site. They may not immediately connect that it stands for `programming puzzles and code golf` but in this particular case that doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### See also [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

**Abbreviations marked with a star (*) are chat specific.**

**ATO**: [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com); a website similiar to TIO where newer versions of languages are hosted. Created by [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger).

***The Bakery**: [The Nineteenth Bakery](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123853/the-nineteenth-bakery), the room where spam and off-topic messages from [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) are moved, kept as a gallery room so that users whose messages are moved aren't notified (as compared to [Trash](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82806/trash), where users get notified if their posts are moved to this room). Currently frozen.

***Butter**: Spam messages, especially when moved to The Bakery. Originated from [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26377157#26377157)

**Catalog**: A type of simple [on-topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5738/43319) challenge where the challenge's aim not so much to find a winner as it is to create a catalog of solutions in many languages.

**CG**: [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info); a challenge to solve a particular problem with the shortest code.

**CGCC**: [Code Golf & Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/); our official abbreviation for the main Stack Exchange site for coding competitions.

***CMC**: Chat Mini Challenge; a less formal [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge posted in chat. Answers are expected as replies to that message, and in the form `Language, XX bytes: [solution](link-to-code-running-service)`. [Example](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=37546121#37546121).

***CMC / CMegaC**: Chat Mega Challenge; usually a challenge posted jokingly in chat due to it being very involved or outright impossible. [Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=40275879#40275879).

***<initial>MC / <language>MC**: <language> Mini Challenge; Acronyms of this form are usually Chat Mini Challenges for specific languages, typically used during LYALs for that language.

***CMM**: Chat Mini Meta (question); a less formal [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/) question posted in chat. [Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=40679641#40679641).

***CMP**: Chat Mini Poll; a request for opinions on a stated question, often about programming language design. [Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40329706#40329706).

***CMQ**: Chat Mini Question; usually an alternative to a **CMM**, but more general (not necessarily restricted to Meta-like questions)

**CnR**: [Cops and Robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/cops-and-robbers/info); challenges where one person has to "crack" another person's code.

**CR**: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/); jokingly our archenemy in the sense that they value efficient legible code while we value obscure inefficient code.

**CW**: [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740), a type of post which especially invites collaboration editing by the community

**Eleven** / **11**: To delete something using moderator powers, e.g. "Yeah, the post is gone, Dennis 11'd it". *mod abuse -> mod abuse!!! -> mod abuse !!11!1!! -> mod abuse !!eleven!1!! -> mod abuse eleven -> eleven*

**FGITW**: [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem); a quick submission to a just-posted challenge, typically used in reference to the problem that fast answers get more visibility and upvotes than later but better ones.

**Hammer**: To close a challenge single-handedly; users that have a gold tag badge in one of the posts's tags have the privilege to close it as a duplicate by themselves; moderators can also single-handedly close *any* question.

**Hello, World!**: A simple program outputting "Hello, World!". May also refer to the [chat feed of the same name](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-1162/hello-world) that posts new answers to the [Hello, World! challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422) into TNB.

**HNQ**: [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions); a global page where popular Stack Exchange posts are often featured. Also the corresponding global sidebar.

**KC**: [Kolmogorov Complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/kolmogorov-complexity/info); a challenge to compress a static output.

**KotH**: [King Of The Hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/king-of-the-hill/info); a game where the submissions interact with and compete against each other in some form of game.

***LDQ**: Language Design Question; a question about some aspect of language design. Most commonly found during the Language Design Workshop but also appears during other times.

**LDW**: Language Design Workshop: a chat event every other Wednesday, where it is encouraged to discuss and develop your in-progress languages.

**LotM**: [Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-of-the-month); a monthly event designed to promote lesser-known languages

***LYAL**: [Learn You A Lang For Great Good](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23738/66833), a chat event every other Wednesday, where it is encouraged to discuss and use a specific language for that day - essentially a single day version of LotM

**LQA**: [Low Quality Auto](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats); these are reviews that show up in the review queue from being short or containing only code.

**LQP**: [Low Quality Posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts); posts that are generally of a very low quality, such as spam. Alternatively, used to refer to the linked review queue

**Mother Meta** / **MSE**: [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), the meta site for the entire network, where posts relevant to and about multiple sites are most on-topic.

***NP**: [New Posts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/509028/new-posts); a chat bot operated by [Rydwolf Programs] which posts in TNB whenever a new challenge is submitted on the site, or a new question is posted on Meta.

**Nuke**: Moderators have the power to permanently delete a post, this is called nuking. Also used in reference to "spam nuking", where users flag a post as spam to remove it.

**OEIS**: [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/); as the name says a website that collects all kinds of integer sequences and assigns them a name, e.g. the squares are [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290). Frequently cited in [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges.

**OP**: [Original poster](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m); the author of the challenge. Also used for [Original Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12537/43319); when talking about the challenge text itself.

**OWC**: [Objective Winning Criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8130/43319); a requirement for all challenges on the site.

**PopCon**: [Popularity Contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info); a competition where the answer with the highest vote tally (upvotes minus downvotes) wins. Note that popcons are generally discouraged, and ones that are "do X creatively" are simply not allowed.

**PPCG**: [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/); the old name for this site.

**Proper quine**: A program that not only prints itself (see *quine*) but also obeys the [proper quine rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine).

**Quine**: A program that prints its own source code. See also *proper quine*.

***RO**: A [Room-owner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) of a chat room is a user with special privileges in that room.

**SEDE**: [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com), a T-SQL based website to get information about posts and other things.

***SP**: [Sandbox Posts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/510186/sandbox-posts); a chat bot operated by [Rydwolf Programs] which posts in TNB whenever a new challenge is proposed in the Sandbox.

**Spec**: Short for the specification of a challenge.

**TIO**: [Try It Online](https://tio.run/); a code testing website for many programming languages, both practical and recreational ones, made by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012).

***TNB**: [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte); our principal chatroom.

***TNBDE**: [TNB Data Explorer](http://ppcg.starmaninnovations.com/tnbde/). Currently down, however you can still use the [Chat Search](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=&room=240)

***Twelve** / ***12**: Similar to Eleven/11, but for [room owner](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/?tab=access#access-section-owner) "abuse" in TNB instead of moderator "abuse". Often used to ask the ROs to move messages to [the Bakery](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123853/the-nineteenth-bakery) e.g. "@RO's can you 12 that please" in reference to a spam post.

**VLQ**: [Very Low Quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous); a type of flag that can be automatically cast on very short posts. These flags used to also [cast automatic downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276269/286591), but this [no longer occurs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330180/allow-us-to-decline-the-automatically-raised-flags/330415#330415). These also show up in the review queue.

**VTC**: [Vote To Close](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions); usually called a CV (Close Vote) on the rest of Stack Exchange.

**VTR** or **VTRO**: [Vote To Reopen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

**VTD**: [Vote To Delete](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

---

## Please add to this list!

Comment: I've added some that are not PPCG-specific but appear rather often here.

Comment: @xnor, is it necessary to repeat ones like OP which are in the glossary that's the first link in the answer?

Comment: Adám, would you object to moving chat-specific ones to a separate answer? There are a few in here which are new to me, and that suggests that they're specific to subcultures within PPCG.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'd rather they stay together so that there are fewer places to look. Maybe mark the chat specific ones with a star or other symbol?

Comment: @PeterTaylor How is that?

Comment: Most browsers have search functions for text in a page :p The asterisk helps, though.

Comment: Oh hey look it's me

Comment: @VoteToClose I've been considering adding abbreviations for the most famous users…

Comment: I'd argue that TNB may be used outside of chat, when referring in questions or comments to relavent discussions

Comment: @BetaDecay True. The distinction isn't very meaningful. A comment to a trivial challenge could e.g. say *-1 trivial: should have been CMC.*

Comment: Isn't 11 Dennis-specific?

Comment: The CMC answer format isn't so strict. That doesn't really work for multi-line programs, for example.

Comment: Also, I think "Catalog" might be a good term to add. Maybe [this link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5738/34718) could be helpful.

Comment: @Adám what, you mean like `D♦` and `ME`?

Comment: 11 seems more like a meme and we don't do [memes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/the-many-memes-of-ppcg) here

Comment: @Poke While that may be, the abbreviation [was used less than a month ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39876518#39876518).

Comment: @Adám Okay? So was [crossed out 44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142452/51785)