# Why there's no latex in PPCG?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Why isn't Latex rendered in questions and answers?  Some other sites such as [math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) support MathJax. It is often useful explaining questions/answers with [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math).

Comment: Although I have voted to close as a duplicate because an earlier question gives the answer, I have also upvoted because IMO this is the second most valuable feature request to improve PPCG. It may be possible to rework this into a non-duplicate question which instead asks for current feedback on community opinion.

Comment: There is LaTeX support in the chat room I think which is slightly confusing if our policy is not to have LaTeX support.

Comment: @Lembik The chat room doesn't have LaTeX, but ATaco's userscripts add LaTeX.

Comment: @dzaima My mistake.

Comment: Despite my VTC, **I would be in favour of LaTeX on PPCG**

Comment: @BetaDecay Me too (what is VTC?)

Comment: @Lembik [Vote to close](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/what-are-the-ppcg-specific-abbreviations-and-terms)

Comment: Turns out I was even more confused that I thought. @orlp pointed out what I meant was http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html . You can click on "start chatjax" and it will render all LaTeX on the page.

Comment: @katana_0 \$\pi \neq \phi\$. It is `\$\pi \neq \phi\$`. Is that latex?